# How to enable dimmed navigation bar in Android 7 (api 24)

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-7.0-nougat

in api 23 and lower, I used:
**setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);**
to display a dimmed navigationbar (dots are replacing the icons).

After I updated to Nougat (API 24), that solution dimmed the navigation bar but dont replace the icons anymore.

Any suggestions?